# How to get Azure Activity Log Summary with alerts/powershell/cli?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azureportal, azure-rbac

I am currently trying to monitor any RBAC changes that happens in our subscriptions example: John.Doe added Sue.Jones as Reader to Resource Group rg-test. Is there any to achieve what I am trying using powershell/cli/rest. From what I have tried and researched, it is not.

Looking in the activity log, for a Write RoleAssignments operation, the summary has all the output I need but when using powershell/cli , you arent able to get what role was assigned or to who. In **summary** you get:

Operation name

Write RoleAssignments

Time stamp

Wed(Eastern Daylight Time)

Event initiated by: John.Doe

MessageShared with 'Sue.Jones'.

Role: Reader

Scope Resource group: 'rg-test'

**Using powershell/cli/alerts you get**

Activity log alert  alert-iamtesting
Time    May 19, 2021 15:29 UTC
Category    Administrative
Operation name  Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write

Correlation ID  0000000-000000000-000000000

Level   Informational

Resource ID /subscriptions/0000000-000000000-000000000/resourceGroups/rg-test/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/0000000-000000000-000000000

Caller  John.Doe

Properties  {"statusCode":"Created","serviceRequestId":"0000000-000000000-000000000","eventCategory":"Administrative","entity":"/subscriptions/0000000-000000000-000000000/resourceGroups/rg-test/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/00000000000000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you view activity log in Azure portal, it calls 3 API endpoints.

The first one is [Activity Logs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activitylogs/list):

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription id}/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2017-03-01-preview&$filter=eventTimestamp ge '2021-05-19T19:52:43Z' and eventTimestamp le '2021-05-20T01:52:43Z' and eventChannels eq 'Admin, Operation' and resourceGroupName eq '{resource group name}' and operations eq 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' and levels eq 'Critical,Error,Warning,Informational'
```

It returns the **caller**, **operationName**, **eventTimestamp**, **resourceGroup** and **the object id of the target user** and **the RoleDefinitionId of the Role**.

The second one is getting the target user:

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/hanxia.onmicrosoft.com/users/{user object id}?api-version=1.6
```

The last one is getting the role:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription id}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/{RoleDefinitionId}?api-version=2015-07-01
```

So you can get all the information you need.

When we use Azure CLI, we should choose [az monitor activity-log list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/activity-log?view=azure-cli-latest#az_monitor_activity_log_list). **BUT** it is only equivalent to the first call above. And we get a property named **resourceId** which is the roleAssignment id.

So we still need to get the roleAssignment with the id. Here is a simple script.

```
# list the activity logs of resource group "AllenTestRG01" in the past 4 hours
$logs = az monitor activity-log list -g AllenTestRG01 --offset 4h | ConvertFrom-Json

# I assume that the first $logs[0] is the log you are tracking. (you should implement your logic here to find the log you need)
$logs[0].resourceId

# list the role assignments for resource group "AllenTestRG01"
$assignments = az role assignment list -g AllenTestRG01 | ConvertFrom-Json

# do a match
foreach ($assignment in $assignments){
    if ($assignment.id -eq $a[0].resourceId) {
        Write-Host "assigned user: " $assignment.principalName  " role: " 
$assignment.roleDefinitionName
    }
}
```